# Checking for occurrence of values in previously retrieved relation through with statement

Tags: sql

Is there a way in SQL to check whether values occur in a relation that was previously retrieved by a with statement?

```
    WITH sp2supplies AS 
(
    --- This gives me all the parts that supplier 2 supplies
    SELECT  Supplypart.partid
    FROM    Supplier
    JOIN    Supplypart USING(supplierid)
    WHERE   Supplier.suppliername = 'Supplier#000000002'
)
  --- Now I'm retrieving all the parts that supplier 1 supplies and supplier 2 doesn't
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    Supplier
JOIN    Supplypart USING(supplierid)
WHERE   Supplier.suppliername = 'Supplier#000000001'
  --- Question: Is there any way to use the previously retrieved list of products
  --- that supplier 2 supplies in order to exclude them?
  --- Ideally, I'd just change this line here.
  AND   Supplypart.partid NOT IN sp2supplies.partid;
```

Isn't there some way to convert the column `sp2supplies.partid` to a list that would work with the `IN` query?

I'm not looking for an equivalent query that uses a completely different approach. I'd rather like to know whether there is some way to achieve this by just changing the last line of my code.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: There are much simpler ways to get the results you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option uses a subquery:

```
WHERE Supplypart.partid NOT IN (SELECT partid FROM sp2supplies);
```

We could also write your requirement using an `EXISTS` clause, but `WHERE IN` and `EXISTS` often are optimized down to the same thing.

Here is what the `EXISTS` version might look like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Supplier s1
INNER JOIN Supplypart sp1 USING(supplierid)
WHERE
    s1.suppliername = 'Supplier#000000001' AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Supplier s2 INNER JOIN Supplypart sp2 USING(supplierid)
                WHERE s2.suppliername = 'Supplier#000000002' AND
                      sp1.partid = sp2.partid);
```

Comment: I understand your proposition. This would mean that I'd make the query in the WITH statement to that subquery. However, I'd like to know whether there is a way to convert the result from the WITH query to a list that I could use to check the (non)-membership on the last line.

Comment: This is the closest thing to what you are literally suggesting.

Comment: Ah, you are right! Now i see it! I'm not executing an entire query, but I'm just selecting the results of the WITH query again. I was hoping that the dot-notation would allow me to do this, but it seems that that's the way it has to be specified. Thanks!